# Driving force of Galvanic cell

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox

Work can be extracted from galvanic cell which has a negative Gibb's free energy. I was wondering what is the driving force of it: I would naturally think its the Gibb's free energy, but the gaps between two fermi levels of the two electrodes also seem to pay a role in the potential difference. Could someone correct me or maybe tell me the connection between these two concepts?